# How to get WMS layer title instead of the layer name in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

When I connect to a WMS service in QGIS, the name displayed in the *layers panel* is the layer `name`.

Can I configure QGIS to always display the layer `title` for WMS layers and fallback on the `name` if the `title` is unavailable?

Comment: According to my knowledge : You can manually assign the name ( I have tested and its working on my end). If you want to display the specific filed then you need to customize that particular python module.....not sure. I may be wrong

Comment: If you suggest that I modify existing QGIS functionality, I might pass this one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know that's not possible but feel free to add a feature request.

Comment: My bad, I found an existing *feature request* (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4002) which keeps being pushed to the next version. It seems like a simple change, but I might be wrong then :)